# Mutating an item inside of nested loops

Tags: rust, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a program to evenly (or as close to possible) distribute points about the surface of a sphere. I'm trying to achieve this by placing N points randomly about a unit sphere, and then running multiple steps where the points repel each other.

The problem is in the loop over the points array. The code below loops over each point, and then the loop inside that, again loops over each point and calculates the repulsive force between each point pair.

```
for point in points.iter_mut() {
    point.movement = Quaternion::identity();
    for neighbour in &points {
        if neighbour.id == point.id {
            continue;
        }
        let angle = point.pos.angle(&neighbour.pos);
        let axis = point.pos.cross(&neighbour.pos);
        let force = -(1.0/(angle*angle)) * update_amt;
        point.movement = point.movement * Quaternion::angle_axis(angle, axis);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
src/main.rs:71:27: 71:33 error: cannot borrow `points` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
src/main.rs:71         for neighbour in &points {
```

and the explanation

```
the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `points` until the borrow ends
```

I'm fairly new to Rust, coming from a C++ background, and I've got no idea how to make this kind of pattern work in Rust.

Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated, as I'm now absolutely stuck for ideas.

Comment: `points.iter_mut()` could be written `&mut points`.

Comment: Certainly the fundamental idea you wish to achieve cannot be done in safe Rust code; the read and write stuff will need to be separated in some way to make it expressible in safe code.

Answer (score 12):

There's a few ways one can write this.

One is your suggestion, of separating movements into a separate vector, since that ensures that the mutable borrow of the movement value doesn't force the compiler to conservatively disallow access to the rest of `points` to avoid mutable borrows from aliasing. In Rust, `&mut` reference can never alias: if values are accessible by exactly one path, it is guaranteed that any/all mutations will be memory safe, if there is aliasing it takes more effort (including runtime checks) to ensure that mutations are safe.

Another is to use indicies for the outer loop:

```
for i in 0..points.len() {
    let mut movement = Quaternion::identity();
    for neighbour in &points {
        if neighbour.id == points[i].id {
            continue
        }
        // ...
        movement = movement * Quaternion::angle_axis(angle, axis);
    }

    points[i].movement = movement
}
```

A third method is to change how the loops work: when considering the interaction between a point and its neighbour, update both the point and the neighbour at the same time. This allows one to iterate "triangularly": point `0`  interacts with `1..n`, point `1` interacts with `2..n`, ... (where `n = points.len()`). This can be done in a way that the compiler understands won't alias.

First one must reset all `movement`s to `1`. The main loops then consist of an outer loop that selects the single element, and then one can "reborrow" the iterator for the inner loop. The outer loop cannot use `for`, since `for` will take ownership of the iterator, fortunately, though, `while let` allows one to write this neatly:

```
for point in &mut points {
    point.movement = Quaternion::identity()
}
let mut iter = points.iter_mut();
while let Some(point) = iter.next() {
    // this reborrows the iterator by converting back to a slice
    // (with a shorter lifetime) which is coerced to an iterator 
    // by `for`. This then iterates over the elements after `point`
    for neighbour in &mut iter[..] {
        // `neighbour` is automatically distinct from `point`

        let angle = point.pos.angle(&neighbour.pos);
        let axis = point.pos.cross(&neighbour.pos);
        let force = -(1.0 / (angle*angle)) * update_amt;
        point.movement = point.movement * Quaternion::angle_axis(angle, axis);
        neighbour.movement = neighbour.movement * Quaternion::angle_axis(angle, -axis);
    }
}
```

NB. that I believe that `axis` must be reversed for the `neighbour` update. (I haven't compiled this, but hopefully it's close.)

Theoretically, the latter offers an approximately 2× speed-up vs. any of the other suggestions so far. At least, it reduces the number of calculations of `angle`, `axis` & `force` from `n * (n - 1)` to `n * (n - 1) / 2`.

Comment: `iter[..]` doesn't compile, says `error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `std::slice::IterMut<'_, usize>`. Full similar example:
```
fn main() {
    let tests: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut sum = 0;
    let mut iter = tests.iter_mut();
    while let Some(test) = iter.next() {
        for neighbour in &mut iter[..] {
            sum += *test * neighbour;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Comment: it is not possible to index into iter as index trait is not implemented. Is there any way to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer to my own question

```
for (point, movement) in points.iter().zip(movements.iter_mut()) {
    *movement = Quaternion::identity();
    for neighbour in &points {
        if neighbour.id == point.id {
            continue;
        }
        let angle = point.pos.angle(&neighbour.pos);
        let axis = point.pos.cross(&neighbour.pos);
        let force = -(1.0/(angle*angle)) * update_amt;
        *movement = (*movement) * Quaternion::angle_axis(angle, axis);
    }
}
```

By creating a separate vector to hold the movements, rather than having movement be a trait of the point, I can borrow the points vector twice as immutable, and borrow the movements vector once as mutable.

I think a C++ mindset still has me thinking too much in terms of classes, but I may still be wrong about this being a ideal way to go about this sort of pattern in rust. If anyone has a problem with this solution, or just knows a better way to go about it, any suggestions would be great.